# Draw text shapes dynamically

Tags: android, android-drawable

I'm working on an Android project and I want to add shapes to a view dynamically and I can't figure out how to do that with shapes that have text. I've seen a lot of people suggest using a custom `TextView` with a `Drawable` xml shape as the background. My problem is I don't know how to add those dynamically to a view with different positions. Essentially I want this to display a tree, sort of like a binary tree in which each node can only have two children but the size of the tree and the text that goes in each node will be based on user input. Also the tree will be built from the bottom up. Right now I just have it displaying the correct number of shapes based on how large the input ArrayList is. However I am only using a `ShapeDrawable` which from research I don't think there is a way to add text to that. This is my current code:

In my DisplayTree Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    sequenceList = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("SequenceList");

    drawTree = new DrawTree(this);
    drawTree.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    setContentView(drawTree);

}
```

With custom view:

```
public class DrawTree extends View{

    private ShapeDrawable mDrawable;

    public DrawTree(Context context) {
        super(context);

        mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());

    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

        int x = 30;
        int y = 10;
        int w = 100;
        int h = 100;

        numberOfSequences = sequenceList.size(); 

        for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfSequences; i++){

                mDrawable.setBounds(x, y, x + w, y + h);
                mDrawable.draw(canvas);
                y = y + 200;
        }
    }
}
```

This is a simplified/unfinished version. eventually I will have lines connecting these to other nodes which will be to the right of these shapes. That is why I would like to keep this same technique if possible or find another one where it will be easy to add more shapes to a specific x and y position. I've been stuck on this for a while and would really appreciate any help!